# The installation of Phoebe GUI doesn't recognize my PKG_CONFIG_PATH

Tags: path, pkg-config

I'm trying to install the GUI version of [Phoebe-project version 1.0](http://phoebe-project.org/1.0/download)

on my Mac OS 10.13.6. I have already edited my /.bash_profile and /etc/launchd.conf like below for the paths:

```
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/bin"
export CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export CPPFLAGS=$CXXFLAGS
#export CPATH=/usr/local/include
#export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export ACLOCAL_FLAGS="/usr/local/bin/aclocal-1.15"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib"
export PATH=/sw/var/lib/fink/path-prefix-10.6:$PATH
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5
```

but when I run ./configure I face the error:

```
The configure script needs pkg-config suite to determine
the presence of various graphical libraries. Please install
it and rerun ./configure.
```

Here I add *part* of the log file warnings for your notice:

```
## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /Users/anya/Downloads/phoebe-gui-       0.31a/autoconfig/missing --run aclocal-1.10'
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='${SHELL} /Users/anya/Downloads/phoebe-gui-    0.31a/autoconfig/missing --run tar'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /Users/anya/Downloads/phoebe-gui-0.31a/autoconfig/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /Users/anya/Downloads/phoebe-gui-0.31a/autoconfig/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /Users/anya/Downloads/phoebe-gui-0.31a/autoconfig/missing --run automake-1.10'
AWK='awk'
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE='depmode=gcc3'
CFLAGS='-I/usr/include'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/include'
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
ECHO_C='ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
GLIB_CFLAGS=''
GLIB_GENMARSHAL=''
GLIB_LIBS=''
GLIB_MKENUMS=''
GNUPLOT=''
GOBJECT_QUERY=''
GREP=''
GTK_CFLAGS=''
GTK_LIBS=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/bin'
LIBGLADE_CFLAGS=''
LIBGLADE_LIBS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /Users/anya/Downloads/phoebe-gui-    0.31a/autoconfig/missing --run makeinfo'
OBJEXT='o'
PACKAGE='phoebe-gui'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='phoebe-devel@lists.sourceforge.net'
PACKAGE_NAME='phoebe-gui'
PACKAGE_STRING='phoebe-gui 0.31a'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='phoebe-gui'
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.31a'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PHOEBE_LIBS=''
PKG_CONFIG='no'
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
VERSION='0.31a'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
am__fastdepCC_FALSE='#'
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__quote=''
am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
have_update_database_database=''
have_update_mime_database=''
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='$(SHELL) /Users/anya/Downloads/phoebe-gui-    0.31a/autoconfig/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(top_builddir)/autoconfig/install-sh -c -d'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''
```

---

Does anybody have any idea?
I also tried to run ./configure along with paths :
./configure CFLAGS="-I/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/bin" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/pkgconfig"
but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message actually says that *.configure* script cannot find tool called **pkg-config**. As you can see from list of dumped variables:

```
PKG_CONFIG='no'
```

You should be able to install it on Mac OS with

```
$ brew install pkg-config
```

Comment: yeah, I reinstalled it using brew. but now face problems with linking gtk

Comment: @Anja thanks, it's hard to say without logs, post it somewhere or better create new question

Comment: Yes I'm going to create a new question @pmod.

Comment: I solved the link problem first using $ brew doctor and then $brew cleanup and then repeating $brew link! The main problem I found was about defining the path s, library path and include paths which I learned a lot from.